# Copy files and preserving directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, find, copy

Here's what I have to do: Find all files which are in the directory `src` (or in its subdirectories) and have `str` in their name and copy them to `dest` preserving the subdirectory structure. For example I have the directory `dir1` which contains `foo.txt` and the subdirectory `subdir` which also contains `foo.txt`. After running my script (with `str=txt` and `dest=dir2`) `dir2` should countain `foo.txt` and `subdir/foo.txt`. So far I have come up with this code:

```
while read -r line; do
    cp --parents $line $dest
done <<< "$(find $src -name "*$str*")"
```

which almost does the job except that it creates `dir1` inside of `dir2` and the desired files are inside `dir2/dir1`. I also tried doing it with the `-exec` option of find but didn't get better results.

Comment: You need `$(cd $src; find . -name "*$str*")` to avoid the unwanted levels of sub-directory.  The 'here-string from `find`' is dubious, at best.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this can be done with `find ... -exec`. Let's say we have the following directory:

```
$ tree
.
└── src
    ├── dir1
    │   └── yet_another_file_src
    └── file_src

2 directories, 2 files
```

We can copy all files that contain `*src*` to `/tmp/copy-here` like this:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*src*" -exec sh -c 'echo mkdir -p /tmp/copy-here/$(dirname {})' \; -exec sh -c 'echo cp {} /tmp/copy-here/$(dirname {})' \;
mkdir -p /tmp/copy-here/./src
cp ./src/file_src /tmp/copy-here/./src
mkdir -p /tmp/copy-here/./src/dir1
cp ./src/dir1/yet_another_file_src /tmp/copy-here/./src/dir1
```

Notice that I used `echo` instead of really running this command -
read the output and make sure that this is what you want to
achieve. If you're sure that this would be what you want just remove
`echo` like this:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*src*" -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/copy-here/$(dirname {})' \; -exec sh -c 'cp {} /tmp/copy-here/$(dirname {})' \;
$ tree /tmp/copy-here
/tmp/copy-here
└── src
    ├── dir1
    │   └── yet_another_file_src
    └── file_src

2 directories, 2 files
```

### EDIT:

And of course, you can always use `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -avz --include "*/"  --include="*src*" --exclude="*" "$PWD"  /tmp/copy-here
```